# can I mix __cdecl export calls with __stdcall import calls in a DLL?

Tags: c++, c, calling-convention

I am writing a module for a third party application; the application `uses __cdecl` calling convention.

At the same time, I have a legacy DLL which `uses __stdcall` calling convention.

Can I create a wrapper that in one end `exports __cdecl` functions, while in the other end `imports __stdcall` functions? which other options do I have?

Thanks,

EDIT:

Here is some extra information that my help clarify my situation.

There is a `third_party.exe` that need to gain access to `skeleton.dll`. The source code skeleton.dll contains the header file below and compiles using __cdecl.

```
#ifdef _EXPORTING
  #define DECLSPEC    __declspec(dllexport)
#else
   #define DECLSPEC    __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
   extern "C" {  
#endif

DECLSPEC int ICD_Create(char* id);
...
...
...
```

Ideally, I would use the skeleton source code to develop my DLL; unfortunately, it would be too time consuming to port my current VB6 legacy code into C++. Given this, I had to hack my VB6 code by following [this guideline](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCEQFjAB&url=http://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2011/04_w16/443022/VB6-Library-Guide-Rev1.pdf&rct=j&q=building%20shared%20libraries%20with%20vb6&ei=2FQ4TrOCFabe0QHyxq3eAw&usg=AFQjCNG1UZrN37UPFIKboP0W4zKul-6CJQ&cad=rja) (It is a work around, but it allows me to use an ActiveX DLL as a standard C DLL).

I am not 100% confident of the modified VB6 calling convention, nor how to modify it. The exercises use __stdcall, and there seem to work fine with a test application I developed. However, when I test it with the third party application, it calls properly certain functions but in other functions it crashes.

The architecture would look like:

```
Application: ThirdParty.exe (out of your control: Uses __cdecl) 
     |
     |
Plugin module: Skeleton.dll (your code)
     |
     |
Legacy DLL: ModifiedVB6.dll (out of your control: Seem to work with __stdcall)
```

The legacy DLL generates a dll, lib and def file; No header file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DLL will typically come with a header file (.h) and an associated import library (.lib) that deal with the calling conventions, exported function prototypes etc.

Simply include the header file, link to the import library, and you will be able to call the functions directly.

That header file will specify that the functions use the `__stdcall` calling convention. You most definitely do not, and should not, write a separate wrapper DLL.  That would be adding a completely gratuitous layer of complexity.

---

Having re-read your question, and your comment, I believe that you have the following architecture:

```
Application (out of your control)
     |
     |
Plugin module (your code)
     |
     |
Legacy DLL (out of your control)
```

The legacy DLL exports its function using `__stdcall`. The application imports function from the plugin using `__cdecl`.

If that synopsis is correct then of course you must import from the legacy DLL using `__stdcall` and export to the application using `__cdecl`.  Since those parts of the interface are outside your control you have no option.

However, I am finding the question and comments very hard to follow. Perhaps I have not fully understood.  Feel free to add more information to clarify in an edit to the question.

---

Following the update I suspect that your problems are all concerning how to interface the VB6 legacy DLL with your C++ DLL.  Since you don't have a header file (.h) for the VB6 DLL you are presumably writing your own translations.

If I recall correctly, VB6 only supports `__stdcall` which is what you are currently using. Your problems are therefore most likely to be due to erroneous translations of the exported VB functions into C++ prototypes.

I think your best course of action is to focus on getting these prototype translations correct. Perhaps you could consider doing that in the context of a separate standalone test project to avoid the complexity of the full application.

If you want further help from Stack Overflow I think you will need to supply the VB6 function declarations and your attempted translations, but I think that would be the subject of new question(s).

Comment: `#include "ThirdParty.h"` is what I mean by include the header file

Comment: David, I updated the question. Hope this helps clarify my situation.

Comment: I've updated my answer, I hope some of this is helpful to you!

Comment: I am using as a name decoration ?VB_Create@@YGHPAD@Z instead of _VB_Create@8. The linker searches the first one, but my understanding is that the second one is the __stdcall one. Do you know know why the linker searches for the first one if I am asking for __stdcall?

Comment: What am I supposed to do with this comment?

Comment: I was just wondering if you are familiar with this name decoration -- ?VB_Create@@YGHPAD@Z. is this __stdcall?

Comment: ok, it seems that I am not familiar with name mangling. I should check that out.

Answer (score 2):

`__declspec(dllexport)` is only needed to tell the compiler to export the identifier from the DLL. This has nothing to do with the calling convention of a function you define (and possibly) export, or that of a function you import. That should be specified separately, and `__stdcall` is fine (but note that vararg functions must be `__cdecl`, since the caller must clean up the stack).

Yes, you could wrap your DLL with another DLL that imports it and exports functions that have `__cdecl` calling convention, but it might confuse users of the DLL. I would not do this, but it is possible.

Comment: I am sorry, I am a newbie with name calling. What is __cdecl(dllexport)? My understanding is that I add __cdecl to specify how the function is managed by the OS. For example, int __cdecl foo(int bar). what you are suggesting is the same as int __declspec(dllexport) __cdecl foo(int bar)

Comment: Also, why would confuse users of the DLL? isn't it the wrapper the only interface they have to know about?

Comment: `__declspec(dllexport)` tells the compiler that this function should be exported by its name from the DLL. Functions without it are private to the DLL and not accessible (directly) from the outside. Someone using the DLL should specify `__declspec(dllimport)` for these functions. -- It is not a calling convention, like `__cdecl` or `__stdcall`, which tell the compiler how function arguments are passed and return values are returned and how these parameters are cleared after the function call.

Comment: __cdecl(dllexport) is invalid syntax. You're combining __cdecl (vs. __stdcall) and __declspec(dllexport).

Comment: Yes, sorry, already edited. I used `__cdecl()` where it should have been `__declspec()`. Too many `__` make me dizzy. <g>

Comment: @Peretz:about the confusion: A DLL usually comes with a header. If they use the header for the original DLL instead of the one for the wrapper, or see both, it might confuse them which to use. But why do you want `__cdecl` instead of `__stdcall` anyway?

Comment: That is right, the client uses __cdecl syntax, and I would be interested in calling a legacy DLL with __stdcall

Comment: The header for the DLL should take care of the calling convention and most of the rest. The user of the DLL should only `#include` it and use the functions as they are declared. I assume that any C and C++ compiler on 32 bit Windows will be able to handle `__stdcall`, since that is what Windows itself uses throughout. Win64 has its own calling convention for ALL functions (with a few exceptions).

Comment: Rudy, what do you mean with vararg must be __cdecl? Any function with argument should use __cdecl?

Comment: Vararg functions don't have a fixed number of arguments, e.g. `int printf(const char *format, ...);`. The called function doesn't know how many arguments will be passed, so it can't clean up the stack after the call. The caller does know how many arguments it passed, so it must do the cleaning up of the stack. That requires that the function is declared `__cdecl`, as this specifies that the caller cleans up the stack, while `__stdcall` lets the called function clean it.